# How to add links in the title for a profile text field

Tags: users

so i have this as a check box for profiles and it is being shown on the registration page as well "I accept the Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy." and i need to make Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy links that point to their respective pages. also i'm using Drupal 6

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Could you provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: in user management > profiles i added a checkbox field titled "I accept the Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy." in that title i need Terms & Conditions to link to the Terms & Condition page and Privacy Policy to link to the Privacy Policy Page. so that when someone registers and they see this check box they can click on those links and read them if they wish before checking the box.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be looking at the [Terms of Use](https://drupal.org/project/terms_of_use) module, which will place the check box on the user registration page. It provides a link to a node, which you create, outlining the terms the user must agree to to register on the site.

On the project page they also mention the [Legal](https://drupal.org/project/legal) module, which provides similar, but more extensive options.

Check both, and see which best satisfies your needs.